# JQuery How do I pass a variable in

Tags: jquery

I have already asked a similar question, but let me try with a sligthly reworded piece of code.
In the code as below, how do I define a general case `$('.add_field_button_sub_'+x)`, instead than several single cases `$('.add_field_button_sub_0'), $('.add_field_button_sub_1'), ...` 
(Yes, I know, I miss some basic understanding on how JS works, please help anyway)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

<title> test </title>
<script src="jquery-3.2.0.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>  
<script  type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
   
    var x = 0; //initial text box count
    $(".add_field_button").click(function(e){ 

  if(x < 4){
 $( "<div><div>Hello! ("+x+")</div><div><button class=\"add_field_button_sub_"+x+"\">Sub Button "+x+"</button></div><br><a href=\"#\" class=\"remove_field\">Remove</a></div><hr>" ).insertBefore( '.add_field_button' );

   var y = 0;
 $('.add_field_button_sub_0').click(function(e){ 


 $( "<div><div>Hello Sub! ("+x+"-"+y+")</div><br><a href=\"#\" class=\"remove_field\">Remove</a></div><hr>" ).insertBefore( '.add_field_button_sub_0' );
 y++; 
    });

 $('.add_field_button_sub_1').click(function(e){ 
 $( "<div><div>Hello Sub! ("+x+"-"+y+")</div><br><a href=\"#\" class=\"remove_field\">Remove</a></div><hr>" ).insertBefore( '.add_field_button_sub_1' );
 y++; 
    });

 $('.add_field_button_sub_2').click(function(e){ 
 $( "<div><div>Hello Sub! ("+x+"-"+y+")</div><br><a href=\"#\" class=\"remove_field\">Remove</a></div><hr>" ).insertBefore( '.add_field_button_sub_2' );
 y++; 
    });

x++; 
}
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
    })
}); </script>  


</head>
<body>
<h3>TEST</h3> </br>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Fonti</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). This will match all button elements having a class that contains `add_field_button_sub_`:

```
$("button[class*='add_field_button_sub_']")
```

Note that it might make more sense to give all your buttons the same class and do your insert operations relative to the current element (referenced by `$(this)` in e.g. the click callback).